# how to make spring-mvc application multi-language?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am working on web service with spring-mvc 4, I have to make it `multilanguage`. Like that: if coming url request contains `'..?lang=tr'` for turkish and `'..?lang=en'` for english. I read on stackoverflow that `<mvc:annotation-driven />` override `LocaleChangeInterceptor`. But when I remove that, app is not working.And I was using [this tutorial](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/spring-3-mvc-internationalization.html#.U0qDyuaFBSc). I didnt find a solution for that yet. For configuration below, messages are always in english even if I switch language. Furthermore I need to get lang messages in java instead of jsp also. But it always return default message there in java class when I syso. I messed up here. and asking for your help.

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
String msg = messageSource.getMessage("deneme", null, "Deault Message!", locale);
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">

     <mvc:interceptors>  
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
              <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

     <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">  
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:/messages"></property>  
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" id="localeChangeInterceptor">  
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" id="localeResolver">  
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"></property>  
    </bean>  

      <!-- Defining which view resolver to use -->
     <bean class= "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" > 
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" /> 
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
     </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: possible duplicate ofhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490558/internationalization-with-spring-mvc?rq=1

Comment: yes. a bit looking like my question. But I am asking how to get message in java also. When I change my xml according to that post, I get 'No bean named 'localeChangeInterceptor' is defined' exception. And this error too : 'Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping' is marked deprecated'

Answer (score 0):

add this to your xml to register your localChangeInterceptor and it will work

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="controller">
    </context:component-scan> 

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">

        </bean>
```